# AJAX Rendering Corrupts HTML

Tags: visualforce, force.com, ajax, html

I started to learn VF a few weeks ago and I created a page (no sidebar, no header) with three sections:
1. **Search**
2. **List of Results**
3. **View Details**

I want to use AJAX when the <kbd>search</kbd> button is clicked and display the section **List of Results**.
The problem is that when I click the <kbd>Search</kbd> button, a slight portion of the HTML code re-rendered is corrupted.

I have uploaded screenshots to clarify the problem.

**Note:** I do not have enough reputation (yet) to display my screenshots so I just put the URLs without http as a workaround.

## Initial State

**Screenshot:**

[image: Image1]

When I click on <kbd>Search</kbd> with some valid search values, the list of results is displayed below the **Search Billing Account** section.

## List of Results (Full Page Refresh - Rendering OK)

**Screenshot:**

[image: Image2]

**HTML Rendered (OK)**
**Screenshot:**

[image: Image3]

So everything is ok here. The  <kbd>fieldset</kbd> is correctly rendered.

## List of Results (AJAX - Rendering Broken)

**Screenshot:**

[image: Image4]

**HTML Rendered (NOK)**
**Screenshot:**

[image]

The <kbd>fieldset</kbd> is corrupted. The rest of the code is ok.

I have encapsulated the section **List of Results** in an <kbd>apex:outputPanel</kbd> as it is recommended so I have no idea what the problem is here.
I have looked for similar problems on the web but I did not find anything.

## Source code:

```
<body class="locale_en">
    <header>
        <div class="banner-top"></div>
        <div class="banner-bottom" />
        <!-- <div class="banner-security-logo" /> -->
        <!--<div class="banner-bc-logo" /> -->
        <!-- <div class="banner-circle" /> -->
    </header>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">

                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12 portlet">

                        <apex:form >
                            <apex:outputPanel id="searchBillingAccountSection">
                            <c:section sectionTitle="Search Billing Account" >
                                <p>Search for a specific account by filling in the form fields below.</p>
                                <apex:outputPanel id="errorContainer">
                                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!hasError}">
                                        <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="alert alert-error" >
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                                            <apex:messages />
                                        </apex:outputPanel>
                                    </apex:outputPanel>
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                                <div class="alert alert-error" style="display:none">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Error 1</li>
                                        <li>Error 1</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>  

                                <div class="mbs-table">
                                    <div class="mbs-row">
                                        <apex:outputlabel value="{!$Label['Search_Value']}" styleclass="mbs-label mbs-cell mbs-mandatory" for="searchField" />
                                        <apex:inputText required="false" value="{!searchText}" tabindex="0" 
                                            title="Enter a search criteria" id="searchField" styleClass="mbs-cell span12"/>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="mbs-row">
                                        <apex:outputlabel styleclass="mbs-label mbs-cell mbs-mandatory" 
                                            for="searchCriteria">Search Criteria</apex:outputlabel>
                                            <apex:selectList value="{!searchCriteria}" size="1" id="searchCriteria" multiselect="false" required="false" styleClass="span12">
                                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
                                            </apex:selectList>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </c:section>
                            <c:requiredField />

                            <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="mbs-button-bar">
                                <apex:commandLink action="{!doSearch}" id="submitButton" styleClass="btn btn-primary" rerender="listOfResults, errorContainer" >Search
                                </apex:commandLink>
                                <!-- rerender="listOfResults, errorContainer" status="status"/> -->
                            </apex:outputPanel>

                            <apex:actionStatus id="status">
                                <apex:facet name="start">
                                    <div    style="position:absolute;top:50%; left:50%;padding:10px;border:1px solid #eaeaea;background-color: #F5F5F5;">Ajax request in progress...</div>
                                </apex:facet>
                            </apex:actionStatus>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        </apex:form>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="row-fluid">
                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="span12" layout="block" >
                        <apex:outputPanel id="listOfResults">
                        <apex:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="{!AND(NOT(ISNULL(results)),(NOT(results.size == 0)))}" styleClass="portlet">
                            <apex:form >                                                
                                <c:section sectionTitle="List of Results" >
                                    <apex:dataTable value="{!results}" var="account"  id="tableOfResults"
                                        styleClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
                                        onRowClick="jsBASelected();">

                                        <apex:column >
                                            <apex:facet name="header">AR Customer #</apex:facet>
                                            <apex:outputText value="{!account.AR_Customer_Number__c}" />
                                        </apex:column>
                                        <apex:column >
                                            <apex:facet name="header">Customer Name</apex:facet>
                                            <apex:outputText value="{!account.Customer_First_Name__c} {!account.Customer_Last_Name__c}" />
                                        </apex:column>
                                        <apex:column >
                                            <apex:facet name="header">Location</apex:facet>
                                            <apex:outputText value="{!account.Location__c}" />
                                        </apex:column>
                                        <apex:column > 
                                            <apex:facet name="header">Action</apex:facet>
                                            <apex:commandLink value="View Details" action="{!billingAccountSelected}" styleClass="btn">
                                                <apex:param name="selectedAccount" value="{!account.AR_Customer_Number__c}" 
                                                    assignTo="{!selectedAccount}" />
                                            </apex:commandLink>
                                        </apex:column>

                                    </apex:dataTable>
                                </c:section>
                            </apex:form>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </div>

            <div class="span8">

                <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="portlet" rendered="{!accountSelected}">
                    <c:section sectionTitle="Billing Account Information">
                        <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" id="theTabPanel" >
                            <apex:tab label="Account" name="accountTab" id="accountTab">
                                content for tab one</apex:tab>
                            <apex:tab label="Invoice Preferences" name="invoiceTab" id="invoiceTab">
                                content for tab two</apex:tab>
                            <apex:tab label="Payment Arrangement" name="paymentTab" id="paymentTab">
                                content for tab three</apex:tab>
                            <apex:tab label="Collection Policy" name="CollectionTab" id="CollectionTab">
                                content for tab four</apex:tab>
                        </apex:tabPanel>
                    </c:section>
                </apex:outputPanel>

            </div>
        </div> <!-- Row -->

    </div>  <!-- Container -->

</body>
```

Comment: just interesting: any reason to use many `form` tags at one page (thinking about view state)?

Comment: @mast0r multiple forms get merged into a single view state as of some releases ago

Comment: `<div class="banner-bottom" />` is not html valid, should be  `<div class="banner-bottom"></div>`

Comment: Could you add `c:section` code?

Comment: @Seb__Wagner Right man, Summer 12 release

Answer (score 2):

*Legend Tag* only can contains **display:inline** elements, `<h2>` is a **display:block** element.

Try removing the `<h2>` within `c:section`:

```
<legend><h2>{!sectiontitle}</h2></legend>
```

by

```
<apex:component >
    <apex:attribute name="sectiontitle" type="String" description="TODO: Describe me"/>
  <fieldset>
      <legend>{!sectiontitle}</legend>
      <apex:componentBody />
  </fieldset>

</apex:component>
```

In addition you could **style** legend tag by css:

```
<style> legend{font-weight:bold;} </style>
```

**In deep:**

Maybe you are asking why h2 works by reloading (complete-reflow) but not by "ajax" (partial-reflow). The browser is your friend and it fix the block element on complete reflow, while fix other broken html too. I don't know why not all html is repaired on partial reflow (It should be for performance issues I assume)

Comment: To all: Thank you for your interest in my problem.

To Martin: Good catch. 
It works as expected now and I am grateful for two reasons:
1 - The problem is fixed.
2 - I learned something extremely important about HTML today so thanks a lot.

Comment: This means that you could solve your issue ?

Comment: It is exactly what it means. I updated my <c:section> component by removing the <h2> tag from the <legend> tag and updated my stylesheet to style the <legend>. The rendering is not broken anymore so thanks again :)

Comment: glad to know :)